# Facing C# Generic List problem what could be the problem?

Tags: c#, list, generics

This is my code,

```
public int countItems(List<T> Items)
{
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Err.. other than your horrible casing, and the fact it always returns 0? :-) More detail might be useful :-)

Comment: Clarify what you're asking, or this will be closed very quickly.

Comment: clean code, really clean I mean really really clean.

Comment: the code is huge but the return type is int so i didn't feel its important to put the whole code all i needed is the <T> thing i am new to generics in C# thanks though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the method isn't in a type that declares the type-parameter `T`, it needs to do so of its own accord:

```
public int countItems<T>(List<T> Items)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 Otherwise it won't work correctly ;)

Comment: why do we need to have an other <T> before countItems?

Comment: @softplaza: `T` is simply a naming- *convention* for type-parameters. Without explicitly specifying it as a type-parameter in the method-declaration, it would appear to the compiler as though it is the simple name for some *other* type, such as `class T { } `.  Since (presumably) there is no such type for which you could use a simple name in this context, it complains.

Comment: Of course, it may still not be correct. Consider that there may be more than 0 items in the List. What a strange question...

Answer (score 1):

[image: XKCD Random Number]

Same with your code.

Comment: I need a generic List how do i do it?